# how to Building Universal UAP application from windows phone 8.1 pivot control

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I'm new to Windows Universal Apps (UAP 10) applications. We are migrating an application in windows phone 8.1 to windows 10 UAP application. Phone application has Pivot control, since pivot doesn't exists on Windows store, is there a way to easily migrate to windows store with alternate approach for pivot control.

Are there any good real time samples for universal apps (UAP 10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Pivot control. The Pivot is available for the universal device family for Windows 10. It is no longer Windows Phone only.

This is specifically stated in the [Windows universal app platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) overview (see the Adaptive controls and panels section), and you can find the Pivot in the Windows 10 apps toolbox if you install the SDK.

For samples see [Get the Windows universal samples for Windows 10](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526492)

For a deep look at Windows 10 development check out the [build conference](http://buildwindows.com) starting 29 April.

Comment: Does it looks good If we have Pivot control in Windows store application ?